# Decode html special character - Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I've a field with html data in a MySql table.
I get the data in JSON format, whith a service. It's OK.
When display that data in a template, it's a simple text.

The controller(ts):

```
export class CursoComponent implements OnInit {
  cursos: Cursos[];
  constructor(cursosService: CursosService) { 
    cursosService.obtenerDatos(0, '')
    .subscribe(
      (data) => { this.cursos = data; console.log(this.cursos); },
      (error) => { console.log(error); }
    );
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

The template (html):

```
<div class="grid-container">
    <h1 class="mat-h1">Cursos</h1>
    <mat-grid-list cols="3" rowHeight="350px">
      <mat-grid-tile *ngFor="let curso of cursos">
        <mat-card class="dashboard-card">
          <mat-card-header>
            <mat-card-title>
              {{curso.title}}
              <button mat-icon-button class="more-button" [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu" aria-label="Toggle menu">
                <mat-icon>more_vert</mat-icon>
              </button>
              <mat-menu #menu="matMenu" xPosition="before">
                <button mat-menu-item>Expand</button>
                <button mat-menu-item>Remove</button>
              </mat-menu>
            </mat-card-title>
          </mat-card-header>
          <mat-card-content class="dashboard-card-content">
            <div>{{curso.introtext}}</div>
          </mat-card-content>
        </mat-card>
      </mat-grid-tile>
    </mat-grid-list>
  </div>
```

Attach images:[image: View and console Image]

Comment: Try binding to `[innerHtml]` to display html content. `<div [innerHtml]="cursor.introtext"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Angualr security system defends against XSS attacks by sanitize HTML tags and change them to [HTML entities](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp).
In order to bypass this defence, bind your data into `innerHTML`.

Instead of:

```html
<div>{{curso.introtext}}</div>
```

Put

```html
<div [innerHTML]="curso.introtext"></div>
```

Notice that this will not work with `style`s embedded in your HTML tags in the data you are binding.

In order to bypass this as well, you should use [DomSanitizer](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer).

TypeScript:

```js
import { SafeHtml, DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

constructor() {
   private sanitizer: DomSanitizer,
}

public getIntro(): SafeHtml {
   return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(this.curso.introtext);
}
```

HTML:

```html
<div [innerHTML]="getIntro()"></div>
```

Comment: @WalterLauxmann sure! Ill appreciate if you'd mark my solution with V. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**Solved!**
Thanks to David and Ron Rofe!

I implements this:
Controller (ts):

```
import { SafeHtml, DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';
...
export class CursoComponent implements OnInit {
  cursos: Cursos[];
  constructor(cursosService: CursosService, private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
    cursosService.obtenerDatos(0, '')
    .subscribe(
      (data) => { this.cursos = data; console.log(this.cursos); },
      (error) => { console.log(error); }
    );
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  public getHtml(texto: string): SafeHtml {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(texto);
  }

}
```

HTML:

```
...
          <mat-card-content class="dashboard-card-content">
            <div [innerHTML]="getHtml(curso.introtext)"></div>
          </mat-card-content>
...
```